# Can't get Steam to work

Tags: steam, 17.10

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 64-bit. Steam gets stuck as in the following image. What can I do?

[image]

```
Specs: 
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory      : 8069MB (2241MB used)
Machine Type        : Notebook
Operating System        : Ubuntu 17.10
-Display-
Resolution      : 1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Unknown
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Audio Devices-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
```

Comment: Please [edit] and post the hardware specs and proprietary drivers versions you may have installed.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel`... (The `OpenGL Renderer  :  Unknown` suggests the Intel Graphics drivers weren't properly installed).